# No water bath canning

Tags: food-safety

I want to use the same recipe for green tomatoes and other vegetables. Is it safe. I do not use water bath
My recipes used 3 parts vinegar to 1 part water. I use it for cayenne peppers.

Answer (score 1):

"No water bath" meaning "Pressure canner only, used correctly" - probably good.

"No water bath" meaning you don't process the jars by any Gererally Reconized As Safe process - not safe, unless you store the jars refrigerated, generally.

There are methods that are GRAS that don't involve canning at all, such as fermented pickles, but those don't start with 3/4 vinegar - they start with a percentage of salt, and the favorable bacteria produce (mostly lactic) acid. They also don't result in a "canned" product, but rather a pickled one that will keep fairly long, especially if kept cool.

Comment: I agree that this is not a canned item. I still wonder if it might be a safe pickle. The addition of vegetable matter to 100% vinegar (as in herbal vinegar) is considered safe, and I don't know where the boundary is for a vinegar-based pickle to be safe without canning.